# Dropped table using SSDT but table still in SCMP file

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools

I'm running MS Visual Studio 2015 with SSDT 14, connecting to MS SQL Server 2015.  I used SSDT to drop an unused table, and published my changes to the database schema.  No problem so far.

The dropped table is still present in the SchemaCompare (`.scmp`) file:

```
<SelectedItem Type="Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SchemaModel.SqlTable, Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
  <Name>dbo</Name>
  <Name>DROPPED_TABLE</Name>
</SelectedItem>
```

Everything I've researched leads to the *idea* of schema comparisons, not the *file* that handles it.  How do I get SSDT to remove the table from the schema compare file, lest it try to recreate a table for which it has no SQL script?

Comment: Connect to the actual database that you dropped the table in. Does it exist?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: No, the table correctly does not exist in the database.  I think it was dropped when I published the changes (if that matters).

Comment: It shouldn't matter if the table shows in the schema compare file. There will be nothing to compare it _to_ if it's not in the project or the database. If you really need it out, just edit those lines out of the scmp file.  Not sure if it will save without that table next time you run the compare and select/deselect something. I do know that dropped tables in the source won't show up in the compare unless it's to drop them in the target.